# Google Sheets API Bad Request Error (postman)

Tags: google-api, postman

[image]

I've been working on accessing the Google Sheets API, and while I managed to pass the authentication part successfully, I'm now facing an issue. I keep receiving a "bad request" error as the response.

To give some context, I have included the following scopes in my authentication request:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

Any insights or suggestions on what could be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your image and Sheets API. Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation and your current issue?